# Is therapy drawing allowed in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, drawing, art, depiction, cartoon

For many years throughout my childhood, I have used drawing as a way of release. Recently I found out drawing was unhalaal and out of the fear for Allah. I have not drawn a picture since. This is been waging on my mind and it's slowly making me mentally unstable.  The release that helped keep me stable is gone and I truly cant take it. My depression is coming back, my anxiety is also heightened.

I went to a Muslim school where my Muslim teacher, who was head of the mosque assured me it was only haraam to sculpt and not to draw. But after reading different things online, I became confused and scared.

I draw people as it calms me the most and even aspired to be a comic artist but after being confused, I haven't drawn anything and feel as though I've lost a big part of myself and have lost my best skill.

I need to know from the Islamic community if it is okay to continue my aspiration.  Is therapy drawing allowed in Islam?

I only wished I could've asked the Nabi (SAW) Shukran for any guidance you can give me.

Comment: Drawing is not haram. There is a difference of opinion on drawing living things (humans, animals, etc) - But apart from that, drawing is halal. And anyways, listen to your local shaykh, and leave that which confuses you from the online world. The online world is filled with pseudo-shaykhs who call to misguidance and depend on translated works that have been propagated by a certain school. Salam